# post httpclient angular 5 and C# webapi

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, angular5

I am using httpclient and post method to send object to C# web api. This works fine in local. But on server it gives error.

my post method in service.ts is like ....

```
post(url:string, data): Observable<any> {
    // console.log(data);
    //Construct URL
    let URL = this.APIURL + url;                      
    return this.http.post(URL, data)               
            .map(
                (response: HttpResponse<any>) => {                       
                        const data = response;
                        return data;                        
                }                   
            )
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));                
  }
```

and in compoenent.ts file, I am making call as follows...

```
const newprod = { "proid": form['prodid'], "prodDescription": form['prodDescription'] };

this.myService.post('Products/PostProduct', newprod)
    .subscribe((data: string[]) => { 
 --- other code ----
 });
```

This works fine in local, but once I deploy api and my application on test server, it gives viered error '500 internal server error'. And when I see 'Network' tab, it gives exception error,

```
ClassName":"System.FormatException","Message":"Input string was not in a correct format.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":".....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pipe to map response...

```
import {map} form 'rxjs/operators';

...
public getSomeData() {
    this.httpClient.post(BASE_URL + 'api/SomeTest/SomeAction', {'some_conf': 123})
        .pipe(
            map(res: any => {/* todo */ return res.json();}));
}
```

Then...

```
service.getSomeData()
    .subscribe(...
```

Or maybe need to use some headers...

```
// tslint:disable-next-line
let headers = new HttpClient();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
// some auth params, tokens maybe need
this.httpClient
    .post(
        BASE_URL + 'api/SomeTest/SomeAction', 
        JSON.stringify( {'some_conf': 123} ), 
        { headers: headers })
    .pipe(...
```

In c# api...

```
public class SomeTestController: ApiController
{
    [Route("api/SomeTest/SomeAction")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeAction(int some_conf) 
    {
        // todo ...
    }
```

Or...

```
// maybe some auth
[Authorize(Roles = "admin,moderator")]
[Route("api/SomeTest/SomeAction")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeAction([FormBody]string body_text)
{
    // todo ...
}
```

Add in Web Api Router Configs, some supported formats

```
...
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
```

Try this...